# Fast uniform generation of random graphs with given degree sequences - any implementation?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, random-graphs

The paper below presents a linear-time algorithm for uniform generation of random graphs with given degree sequences [1].

This is very interesting in practice, but I found no implementation. However, I guess some colleagues may have done one, or may be working on it.

**Is anyone aware of such an implementation?**

[1] Fast uniform generation of random graphs with given degree sequences.
Andrii Arman, Pu Gao, Nicholas Wormald.
Extended abstract at FOCS'19,
full version: https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.03446

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation by Nick Wormald and colleagues is available from [his webpage](https://users.monash.edu.au/%7Enwormald/).

Answer (score 4):

We have an implementation in C, freely available, you just need to contact me.

Nick Wormald

Comment: That's great, thanks!